# Category Sources plugin not showing headings

Tags: entries, categories

Like the title tells you the headings, titles of the category groups, are not showing in the sidebar.

[image]

This is a screenshot from the github page of the plugin.
The "FOOD" and "DRINKS" titles are not being displayed when I use the plugin. In the source I can see:

```
<li class="heading"><span></span></li>
```

So the plugin knows that there should be a heading but It does not fill the `<span>` element.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on the fresh install of the latest Craft [2.6.2989](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-6-2989) and the latest [Category Sources zip](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources/archive/master.zip) and it working as expected where "Food" and "Drinks" are the Category Group names.

[image]

I'd double check you're running the latest of each.